# why data is not being inserted in import class

Tags: excel, laravel

my task is to import an xlxs file in mysql in Laravel. I am using `maatwebsite excel` laravel package to work with excel files. I made an import class using `php artisan make:import exceltosql`. In import class i simple write an insert query but it's not working. I tried a lot but no way.  I simple dd($rows) it shows all records in excel file. But issue is that there no simple query running here.

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        // dd($rows);
        $i=0;
        foreach($rows as $row){
            if($i==0){
        //
            }else{
                $data["category_id"]=1;
                $data["website_title"]=$row[1];
                 $data["example_link"]=$row[11];
                 $data["link"]=$row[2];
                 $data["da"]=$row[3];
                 $data["pa"]=$row[4];
                 $data["ss"]=$row[5];
                 $data["total_visitors"]=$row[8];
                 $data["alexa_rank"]=$row[6];
                 $data["country"]=$row[7];
                 $data["note"]=$row[12];
                $data["dofollow"]=1;
               
                $link=Link::create($data);
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

No error is shown, simple runs successfully but no data inserted in my database. I have done fillable in Link model.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you dump $data and show it, before creating?

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm also facing the same issue and didn't get any solutions